# Problemas com o Composer e Laravel 5.0 no Mac El Capitan

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Estou com o seguinte erro, após executar um comando para instalar um projeto versionado.

**Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error**

[RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' n
  ot found in [PASTA_DO_PROJETO]/bootstrap/app.php on line
  14

Arquivo composer:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "pagarme/pagarme-php": "dev-master",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0",
        "lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel": "~4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Tente fazer um *composer dump-autoload* e tente novamente.

Comment: Já o fiz, tambem ja executei composer install --no-scripts e nada ainda

Comment: Remova a pasta vendor, verifique seu *app.php* em /bootstrap, tente *composer dump-autoload* e *composer install* novamente e veja se volta ao normal... pois essa falha ai é no arquivo app.php que inicia a aplicação ele apenas lê o *Application* do Laravel.

Comment: Fiz conforme recomendado, <pre> laravel/framework v5.0.9 requires ext-mcrypt * -></pre>, teria que habilitar o mycrpt do php mas o mesmo já está habilitado tenho outros projetos com laravel e eles funcionam perfeitamente

Comment: Ao menos já achou o Application. Agora é o mcrypt... veja se seu .env já possui uma key para acessar o sistema.

Comment: Ele não deixa eu criar a key, nem executar qualquer comando do artisan PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /Users/emiddev/Code/farmin-pagamento/bootstrap/app.php on line 14

Comment: Mesmo erro... =( Desculpe não poder ajudar... realmente não sei o que sugerir....

Comment: Pois é já revirei a internet e não encontro nada, inclusive já instalei em outra máquina e o mesmo erro acontece